# Who are "those guys from Season 4" that Yu-Gi-Oh The Abridged Series references?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

In the Yu-Gi-Oh! The Abridged Series stand-alone video [Pharaoh's Throne](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVxAqqTM-IM), Yami Yugi sings the lines:

> *♪ Not for nothing but your nonsense is kind of a bore ♪*
>
> *♪ I was more intimidated by those guys from Season 4 ♪*

While the lines are very clever-sounding and inherently funny IMO even without context, I am curious as to who it is referring to.  **Who are "those guys from Season 4" that the song references who are apparently a joke?**  Unfortunately, the YGO:TAS is a very extensive series at this point, and I am not familiar with all of the episodes.

Comment: I assume it's talking about the people in the Leviathan/Orichalcos arc - Dartz and his goons.

Comment: @senshin If you feel confident about your statement then feel free to make an answer.

Comment: Not too confident about that, I'm afraid. I'll think about this next time I watch through YGOTAS, though.

Comment: @senshin I appreciate the thought, but I was definitely looking for a more... immediate answer.  While the question is still current, as opposed to "someday."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no YGOTAS season 4 yet, so "these guys from season 4" are from the actual show when it starts getting all trippy and Egyptian.